# how to show split view in landscape only in IPhone using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i have video player on the top and there is tableview below the video player. video player has some custom control UI and below in the table view there are some cardview shows video list.
but when the video playback will end then in portrait its showing video view on top and bottom will show tableview. in landscape i want to show two view. left side will show video end playback UI and right side will show the tableview .

[i want to show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehNON.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! Can you add some sample code and a screenshot of your app? This will help us understand your problem better!

Comment: @BrandonMinnick thanks for your reply.... i have added my required my view image. in portrait its showing good. in landscape its showing replay, go to learn, thumbs up/down in proper layout for iphone devices. but i want to show like above screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 8.2 and swift3, in the `Main.storyboard` you have the option where you can see your application with the different Orientation and Device.
You can adapt the view with the orientation that you choose. Like below:

[image]

[Here](https://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/) a great tutorial about Auto Layout with Xcode8.

Hope that helps,

Comment: If the response help you to solve your problem please to accept it as answer. Thank you !